# How can I avoid saving my irssi (irc) password in plain text (yet still log in automatically)?

Tags: irssi

I have this line in my irssi config file:

```
autosendcmd = "/msg nickserv identify [my-password-here] ; wait 2000";
```

I like being able to log in automatically, but I'd rather not save my password in plain text. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Looks like the Arch guys have it all covered: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Irssi#Client_certificates  I can write this all up but this is an older question and I am not sure if you are still interested?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rizon, the  [exact guide is here at wiki.rizon.net](https://wiki.rizon.net/index.php?title=CertFP).

General setup would be that you use `openssl` to create a certificate and a key, concatenate them into one .pem file, create md5 hask and provide the networks ident bot with the hash.